# Access to class fields from lambda function written in class method

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

The code example will be probably more descriptive:

```
class CDialog
{
    CButton* ButtonPtr;
    bool m_Visible;
    void SomeMethod ();
}

class CButton
{
public:
    std::tr1::function<void(void)> Function;
}

void CDialog::SomeMethod()
{
    ButtonPtr = new CButton;
    std::tr1::function<void(void)> TempF = [this]
    {
        this->m_Visible = false;
    };
    ButtonPtr->Function = TempF;
}
```

Now, when I tried to call TempF it appeared to modify some copy of the m_Visible variable instead of the actual value. I wanted to ask if it's default behavior and if there's some way to use it that way. My hotfix used pointers, which worked just fine, but I'm curious if it could be done.

EDIT: I created a minimal example, and it did work.

EDIT2: Fixed the bug with not calling function.

EDIT3: Changed to more accurately match my problem. Assume that Function of CButton is called when button is clicked, and that's confirmed. Still doesn't work.

EDIT4: Took some time to examine it with debugger. Value of "this" pointer used when creating function differs from the value used when calling function. So is there something i did wrong?

EDIT5: Found bug in my code, which fixed & combined with the answers solved my problem. Thanks for all replies, I learned something new today thanks to you!

Comment: [I don't get the same behaviour](http://ideone.com/IuFPh) for some reason (GCC 4.5.1). What compiler are you using?

Comment: What compiler?  This looks like Visual C++ style, but Visual C++ implements an older specification for lambdas.

Comment: Visual C++ 2010. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I still didn't solve the problem (I'm not as fast as you, guys) but I think the answers can point me in the right direction. I'm not sure if it isn't the bug in the other part of my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the C++11 spec (note: VC2010 implements an older form of lambdas, since the spec wasn't finished when they were), `this` can only be captured by *value*, not by reference. So if you do `[&]`, you're capturing everything but `this`.

To do what you want, you must either capture by value `[=]` or capture `this` explicitly: `[&, this]`.

Comment: What does it mean to "capture _this_ explicitly"? How is it understood by compiler? Just as [=this]?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: The stuff in `[]` says what is being captured. You can put names there that will be captured; this allows you to prevent yourself from accidentally capturing stuff you don't want. `this` is one of the things you can put there. I showed you how to capture `this` explicitly.

Comment: But will it be captured by value? Sorry, my knowledge of lamba syntax isn't quite complete.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Yes, it will be captured by value.

Comment: You capture the *pointer* by value, which is effectively the same as capturing the *object* by reference.

Comment: @NicolBolas: To capture `this` explicitly, the syntax is `[this]`, as shown in my answer.  Using `[=]` or `[&]` encourages spaghetti code.

Answer (score 5):

I would use

```
auto TempF = [this](void)
{
    this->m_Visible = false;
};
```

Universal capture, ala `[&]`, is not a good practice.

Comment: This doesn't explain the behavior in the question, does it?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly does "[this]" do? Can just link me to documentation.

Comment: @Bartek: It captures one value, by value, the value of the `this` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your observation is wrong.  You must be doing something else.

In my case, it behaves as expected, by which I mean calling the lambda indeed changes the member variable, not any *copy* of the member variable.

See yourself :  http://ideone.com/DED5k

This behavior is correct. If you don't see this, then either your compiler has bug, or you're doing something else which you didn't mention in the question.